# Removing a known sub-string from a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

I'm having a string "Kishore kumar karaoke tracks", from which I want to remove the substring 'karaoke tracks'. I want the output as 'Kishore kumar'.

For this purpose, I'm using the following line of code:

```
artist = artist.TrimEnd(new char[] {'k','a','r','a','o','k','e', ' ', 't','r','a','c','k','s'});
```

But, I'm getting the output as 'Kishore kum' i.e. i'm not getting the last 2 characters 'ar'.

Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `artist = artist.Replace("karaoke tracks", "").Trim()`

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple `String.Replace` works too:

```
artist = artist.Replace(" karaoke tracks", "");
```

Note I added a space in the front, so the result is `"Kishore kumar"`, rather than `"Kishore kumar "`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do like this

```
artist.Replace(" karaoke tracks",string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
artist = artist.Replace("karaoke tracks", string.Empty).Trim();
```

You could also do this if you wanted to ignore case:

```
artist = Regex.Replace(artist, "karaoke tracks", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

in Trim, you defined which chars you want to delete from `artist`. But it has `r` and `a` chars too.

So when `karaoke tracks` ends, next is `kumar's` `ar`, if you understood what I mean.

You can use replace function as others explained.